# Populate rows of multiple columns based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe

**My dataframe looks like this:**

```
    Date        User    Report    Position    View
1   2019-01-01  B   report_03   Sales_Manager 1
2   2019-01-01  C   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
3   2019-01-01  C   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
4   2019-01-02  B   report_03   Sales_Manager 1
5   2019-01-02  C   report_05   Sales_Manager 1
6   2019-01-02  D   report_06   Sales_Rep     1
7   2019-01-02  D   report_06   Sales_Rep     1
8   2019-01-03  A   report_03   CEO           1
9   2019-01-03  C   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
10  2019-01-03  D   report_06   Sales_Rep     1
11  2019-01-04  A   report_01   CEO           1
12  2019-01-04  C   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
13  2019-01-04  C   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
14  2019-01-04  C   report_05   Sales_Manager 1
15  2019-01-04  D   report_05   Sales_Rep     1
16  2019-01-04  D   report_06   Sales_Rep     1
17  2019-01-05  A   report_01   CEO           1
18  2019-01-05  B   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
19  2019-01-05  B   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
20  2019-01-05  C   report_04   Sales_Manager 1
```

Rows represent log-in information of users for certain reports in a dashboard. Based on the position the user has access to different reports.
The CEO (User A) has access to report_01, report_02 and report_03; Sales Manager (User B & C) have access to report_03, report_04 and report_05; Sales Reps have access to report_05 and report_06.

The user should use every report they have access to every day, but on some days they don't use certain reports at all and on other days they log in more than once. I want to fill in rows where the user didn't log in to their reports with 0 in the View column.

**So the dataframe should look like this:**

```
    Date        User    Report    Position      View
1    2019-01-01  A   report_01     CEO           0
2    2019-01-01  A   report_02     CEO           0
3    2019-01-01  A   report_03     CEO           0 
4    2019-01-01  B   report_03     Sales_Manager 1
5    2019-01-01  B   report_04     Sales_Manager 0
6    2019-01-01  B   report_05     Sales_Manager 0
7    2019-01-01  C   report_03     Sales_Manager 0
8    2019-01-01  C   report_04     Sales_Manager 1
9    2019-01-01  C   report_04     Sales_Manager 1
10   2019-01-01  C   report_05     Sales_Manager 0
11   2019-01-01  D   report_05     Sales_Rep     0
12   2019-01-01  D   report_06     Sales_Rep     0
13   2019-01-02  A   report_01     CEO           0
14   2019-01-02  A   report_02     CEO           0
15   2019-01-02  A   report_03     CEO           0
16   2019-01-02  B   report_03     Sales_Manager 1
17   2019-01-02  B   report_04     Sales_Manager 0
18   2019-01-02  B   report_05     Sales_Manager 0
.
.
.
```

**dput Output:**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17897, 17898, 
17898, 17898, 17898, 17899, 17899, 17899, 17900, 17900, 17900, 
17900, 17900, 17900, 17901, 17901, 17901, 17901, 17901, 17901, 
17902, 17902, 17902, 17902, 17902, 17903, 17903, 17903, 17904, 
17904, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17905, 17905, 
17905, 17905, 17905, 17906, 17906, 17906, 17906, 17906, 17907, 
17907, 17907, 17907, 17907, 17908, 17908, 17908, 17908, 17908, 
17909, 17909, 17909, 17909, 17910, 17910, 17910, 17911, 17911, 
17911, 17911, 17911, 17912, 17912, 17912, 17912, 17913, 17914, 
17914, 17914, 17914, 17914, 17915, 17915, 17915, 17915, 17916, 
17916, 17916, 17916, 17917, 17917, 17917, 17918, 17918, 17918, 
17918, 17919, 17919, 17919, 17919, 17919, 17920, 17920, 17920, 
17921, 17921, 17921, 17921, 17922, 17922, 17923, 17923, 17923, 
17923, 17923, 17924, 17924, 17924, 17924, 17924, 17925, 17925, 
17925, 17925, 17926, 17926, 17926, 17927, 17927, 17927, 17927
), class = "Date"), User = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), report = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L
), .Label = c("report_01", "report_02", "report_03", "report_04", 
"report_05", "report_06"), class = "factor"), Position = c("Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", 
"CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", 
"Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Rep", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", 
"CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", 
"Sales_Rep", "CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", 
"Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", 
"CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", 
"Sales_Rep", "CEO", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", 
"CEO", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "CEO", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", 
"Sales_Manager", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", 
"Sales_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", "Sales_Manager", 
"Sales_Rep"), View = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -130L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your need, you may want to change the first line to the second one. If you want to get data frame for Jan 2019, if there is a day in the period in which no one read any report (say a holiday), the first line of code will not give the zero rows for that day while the second line will.

Also note that it does not check for the uniqueness of name user and position. If there is any duplicated name but more than one corresponding positions, it result will be as though they are all different users.

```
unique.date <- unique(df[,"Date",drop=F])
# unique.date <- seq(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to=as.Date("2019-01-31"), by="1 day")
unique.usr.rpt <- unique(df[,c("User","Report","Position")])

unique.df <- merge(unique.date, unique.usr.rpt)

result <- merge(unique.df, df, by=c("Date", "User", "Report", "Position"), all=T)
result[is.na(result$View), "View"] <- 0
```

EDIT: if the report view privileges are deterministic, we can add some defining lines on top to specify them. What follows then will be largely similar. Whole working code:

```
access <- list(
"CEO" = c("report_01", "report_02", "report_03"),
"Sales_Manager" = c("report_03", "report_04", "report_05"),
"Sales_Rep" = c("report_05", "report_06")
)

access.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(access), function(x) data.frame(x, access[[x]])))
colnames(access.df) <- c("Position", "Report")

unique.usr <- unique(df[,c("User","Position")])
unique.usr.rpt <- merge(unique.usr, access.df, by=c("Position"), all=T)

# What follows is same as before
unique.date <- unique(df[,"Date",drop=F])
# unique.date <- seq(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to=as.Date("2019-01-31"), by="1 day")

unique.df <- merge(unique.date, unique.usr.rpt)

result <- merge(unique.df, df, by=c("Date", "User", "Report", "Position"), all=T)
result[is.na(result$View), "View"] <- 0
```

and you now get the rows you need:

```
> head(result[result$User=="B" & result$Report=="report_05",])
         Date User    Report      Position View
6  2019-01-01    B report_05 Sales_Manager    0
18 2019-01-02    B report_05 Sales_Manager    0
30 2019-01-03    B report_05 Sales_Manager    0
41 2019-01-04    B report_05 Sales_Manager    0
54 2019-01-05    B report_05 Sales_Manager    0
67 2019-01-06    B report_05 Sales_Manager    0
> head(result[result$User=="C" & result$Report=="report_03",])
         Date User    Report      Position View
7  2019-01-01    C report_03 Sales_Manager    0
19 2019-01-02    C report_03 Sales_Manager    0
31 2019-01-03    C report_03 Sales_Manager    0
42 2019-01-04    C report_03 Sales_Manager    0
55 2019-01-05    C report_03 Sales_Manager    0
68 2019-01-06    C report_03 Sales_Manager    0
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what I wanted. For user B entries for report_05 are missing and for user C report_03 is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution based on `tidyr::complete`, also we use `map_if` to add the missing combinations from the dataset, e.g. `User B` and `report_05`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
ndf <- df %>% complete(Date, nesting(User,report,Position), fill = list(View=0))
posrep_df <- df %>% 
                group_by(Position) %>% 
                summarise(report=paste(unique(report), collapse = ',')) %>%
                separate_rows(report,sep='\\,')

ndf %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% split(list(.$Date,.$User)) %>% 
        map_if(~(.x[['Position']] %in% c('CEO','Sales_Manager') && n_distinct(.x[['report']])<3) || 
                (.x[['Position']] %in% c('Sales_Rep') && n_distinct(.x[['report']])<2), 
               ~bind_rows(.x, 
                          anti_join(posrep_df %>% filter(Position==.x$Position[1]),
                                    .x ,
                                    by='report') %>% 
                          mutate(Date=.x$Date[1], User=.x$User[1], View=0)
                         )) %>% 
        bind_rows() %>% 
        arrange(Date, User)

# A tibble: 369 x 5
   Date       User  report    Position       View
  <date>     <chr> <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>
1 2019-01-01 A     report_01 CEO               0
2 2019-01-01 A     report_02 CEO               0
3 2019-01-01 A     report_03 CEO               0
4 2019-01-01 B     report_03 Sales_Manager     1
5 2019-01-01 B     report_04 Sales_Manager     0
6 2019-01-01 B     report_05 Sales_Manager     0
7 2019-01-01 C     report_04 Sales_Manager     1
8 2019-01-01 C     report_04 Sales_Manager     1
9 2019-01-01 C     report_05 Sales_Manager     0
10 2019-01-01 C     report_03 Sales_Manager     0
# ... with 359 more rows
```

We can write a custom function to reduce the amount of parenthesis and calculation inside `map_if`

```
combine_fun <- function(x){
  #browser()
  x_full <- posrep_df %>% 
    filter(Position==x$Position[1]) %>% 
    mutate(Date=x$Date[1], User=x$User[1], View=0)

  x_comp <- x_full %>% anti_join(x, by='report')

  x_final <- bind_rows(x, x_comp)

  x_final
}

#Here a simple example to explore `combine_fun`
df_test <- ndf %>% filter(Date=='2019-01-01' & User=='B')
#Before combine_fun
df_test
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Date       User  report    Position       View
  <date>     <fct> <fct>     <chr>         <dbl>
1 2019-01-01 B     report_03 Sales_Manager     1
2 2019-01-01 B     report_04 Sales_Manager     0
#After combine_fun
combine_fun(df_test)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
   Date       User  report    Position       View
  <date>     <fct> <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>
1 2019-01-01 B     report_03 Sales_Manager     1
2 2019-01-01 B     report_04 Sales_Manager     0
3 2019-01-01 B     report_05 Sales_Manager     0
```

Reformulate `map_if` using `combine_fun`

```
ndf %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)%>%split(list(.$Date,.$User)) %>% 
map_if(.p = ~(.x[['Position']] %in% c('CEO','Sales_Manager') && n_distinct(.x[['report']])<3) || 
             (.x[['Position']] %in% c('Sales_Rep') && n_distinct(.x[['report']])<2), 
       .f = ~combine_fun(.x)) %>% 
bind_rows() %>% 
arrange(Date, User)
```